# JS for loop not working on Live Wordpress website, although it works locally

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rest

everyone. I am a beginner programmer building the website for our own language academy.

I am building a schedule app with JavaScript in WordPress (REST API). the code runs just fine, until it reaches this loop.

Tried for, forEach, and they do not work. I tried modifying the PHP / MySQL settings, and have spent hours around this.

The live website is hosted on Cloudways, and I am using FlyWheel Local locally.

Any ideas? (Thanks)

This is part of the code...

```
teacherBlocks.forEach((t)=>{

    const blockFragment = new DocumentFragment()

    //block info
    const classID = t.te_schedule_class_ID
    const thePermalink = t.te_schedule_class_permalink
    //Create theBlock
    const theBlock = document.createElement('div')
    theBlock.className = `class-desc outlined__dotted`
    theBlock.setAttribute('data-class-id', classID)
    theBlock.setAttribute('tabindex', 0)

    /************************************************************** */
    /** theBlock attributes */

    //Data attributes
    theBlock.setAttribute('teacher-term-id', t.te_teacher_term_id)
    theBlock.setAttribute('teacher-name', t.te_teacher_in_block)
    theBlock.setAttribute('attendance-type', t.te_schedule_attendance_type)
    theBlock.setAttribute('type-of-class', t.te_schedule_lesson_type)
    theBlock.setAttribute('teacher-color', teachColor)

    /************************************************************** */
    /** theBlock Data preparation */

    //Get day
    const dayInBlockTermID = t.te_schedule_day_term_id
    const dayInBlock = t.te_schedule_day
    //Get time
    const timeInBlock = t.te_schedule_time
    //Ready times for height
    const timeInBlockStr = timeInBlock.replace(/:/g,'').replace('-','')
    const startTime = timeInBlockStr.substr(0,4)
    const endTime = timeInBlockStr.substr(4,4)
    //Block height
    const startTimePx = timeNotation[startTime]
    const endTimePx = timeNotation[endTime]
    const blockHeight = (endTimePx - startTimePx)

    //Block styles
    theBlock.style.position = 'absolute'
    theBlock.style.top = startTimePx + 'px'
    theBlock.style.minHeight = blockHeight + 'px'
    theBlock.style.maxHeight = blockHeight + 'px'
    theBlock.style.width = theBlockWidthPx + 'px'
    theBlock.style.backgroundColor = teachColor

    //block text content
    const highlightText = t.te_schedule_block_highlight_text
    const blockText = t.te_schedule_block_normal_text

    //room_label + room_url
    const roomLabel = t.te_room_label
    const roomURL = t.te_room_url

    /************************************************************** */
    /** theBlock Data preparation: Students */

    //Get students
    const profiles = t.te_st_profiles
    const students = t.te_schedule_students //To replace with PROFILES

    //students Div
    const studentNamesDiv = document.createElement('div')
    studentNamesDiv.className = 'student-names-in-block'    

    //Profiles
    if(profiles){
        const profileFragment = new DocumentFragment()

        profiles.forEach(profile =>{
            //delete the 'students' and leave only 'profiles'
            const oldSt = studentNamesDiv.querySelectorAll('[old="yes"]')
            oldSt.forEach(old => {
                old.classList.add('hidden')
            })

            const profileID = profile.st_profile_id
            const profileName = profile.st_profile_name
            const profileSlug = profile.st_profile_slug
            const profileEmail = profile.st_user_email
            
            const profileLink = document.createElement('a')
            profileLink.className = 'profile-link'
            profileLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank')
            profileLink.setAttribute('data-id', profileID)
            profileLink.setAttribute('data-slug', profileSlug)
            profileLink.setAttribute('data-name', profileName)
            profileLink.setAttribute('href', `${scheduleLocalize.teSiteUrl}/st-student/${profileName}`)

            //const copyBtn = document.createElement('span')
            //copyBtn.className = 'copy-btn dashicons dashicons-paperclip'
            //profileLink.appendChild(copyBtn)

            if(profileEmail === null){
                const errorAsterisk = document.createElement('span')
                errorAsterisk.innerHTML = '*'  
                profileLink.appendChild(errorAsterisk)  
            }

            profileLink.innerHTML += profileName + '</br>'

            
            profileFragment.appendChild(profileLink)

        })
        studentNamesDiv.appendChild(profileFragment)
    }
    
    /************************************************************** */
    /** theBlock innerHTML*/

    theBlock.innerHTML += 
    `<div class="block-text-contents">
            ${highlightText ? `<span class="highlight-text"> ${highlightText} </span>` : ''}
            <span class="block-text">${blockText}</span>
    </div>

    <a class="day-time" day-term-id="${dayInBlockTermID}" day="${dayInBlock}" time="${timeInBlock}" target="_blank" href="${thePermalink}">${dayInBlock + ` ` + timeInBlock}</a>

    <div class="block-buttons">
        ${roomLabel != false
            ? `<a target="_blank" class="room-button" href="${roomURL}">${roomLabel}</a>`
            : ``}<a target="_blank" class="report-button" href="${thePermalink}">Report</a>
    </div>`

    /*************************************************** */
    /** Insert the theBlock in its day > teacher column */
    /** They will be sorted by their class Desc ID */

    blockFragment.appendChild(theBlock)
    teacherDiv.appendChild(blockFragment)
})
```

My server on Cloudways: PHP 7.4 -- MySQL MariaDB 10.1 -- server Apache/Nginx

My local server: PHP 7.3.5 -- MySQL 8.0.16 -- server Nginx in Local by FlyWheel

This issue does not happen in my local environment, only on Cloudways.

Does anyone have any ideas of where I could look for more errors?

Update 2021-04-25:
Using DevTools, I found out that the same variable "d" = undefined on my live website whereas it is equal to 1 on my local website.
Trying to identify why.

Comment: Any errors in console? Throwing so many lines of JS without explaining the issue you're facing... :\

Comment: Echoing the above sentiment, please explain in more detail how prod and dev environment differ and what in particular is not working here. Please be as specific as possible

Comment: I just added more info in the question, thanks again.

Comment: Are you familiar with debugging JavaScript in devtools?  Setting some breakpoints and stepping through may give you something helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. Now I realize it was the obvious thing to do. I will add the updates in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally! Found the answer.

In my local server, I had changed one ACF field to return the ID instead of the object.
It now returned this in the json response:
"te_schedule_day_term_id": 247,

On my live website, I had not made this change to the field, so it was returning the whole object, like this:
"te_schedule_day_term_id": {
"term_id": 247,
"name": "Friday",
"slug": "friday",
(...)
}

So, it turns out my JavaScript code was just fine. I found it out while debugging with DevTools; the teacherBlocks array was empty, so I verified the response text and found the difference between the live/local json responses.
(Pretty much a beginner's issue!)